# Why is the character x used to mean extract in linux commands?

Tags: linux

Why is the character `x` used to mean extract in linux commands?

For example, in the command `tar xf helloworld`, the `x` means extract.

Why is `x` used to mean extract instead of `k` or `u`?

Comment: What? Because that's what the authors decided...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't always a clear reason why certain letters are chosen to apply certain options. Especially as there only 26 letters in the alphabet, and sometimes more than 26 options. In this case, long options tend to be used such as `--extract`, or a seemingly random letter. An example in the `tar` command you mentioned is `-h` for `--dereference` - this is what the author chose to use.

In this case, I believe that the `-x` is from e**X**tract. If you say "x" out loud, it sounds like "Ex" - the first syllable of the word.

`-k` is used as shorcut for `--keep-old-files` and `-u` is used for `--update` so they can't be used for `--extract`.